# How do you select descendants of elements in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of divs with textareas in them set to hidden display. When one of those divs is toggled by a button click, I wish to toggle whatever is in them as well (the textareas) because then just the container div is toggled while everything in it is hidden. This is what I want to happen:

```
 $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#specificDiv", "#specificDiv#textareaID").toggle();
});
```

Or

```
 $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#specificDiv", "#specificDiv textarea/allDescendants").toggle();
});
```

The idea of following CSS selector logic did not work.

Comment: `#specificDiv *` would be every descendent of the div.  But hiding the div should hide everything in it as well.

Comment: Just a cross check: Are you sure all the IDs in your document are unique?

Comment: What are you expecting those to do? Even in CSS, #specificDiv#textareaID would not work, as it would necessitate an element with two IDs. Might want to take a look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) for how the jQuery function works.

Comment: All IDs are unique. The #x#x was a poorly worded example. Even with #x.x combinations it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not separate each selector wrapped in quotes. Instead, they should be comma-separated but all wrapped together in quotes:

To find all `textarea` descendants of `#specificDiv`:

`$("#specificDiv, #specificDiv textarea").toggle();`

Or to find just direct `textarea` children of `#specificDiv`:

`$("#specificDiv, #specificDiv > textarea").toggle();`

You may also use `.children()` or `.find()` separately to find either direct descendants or any descendants:

```
$("#specificDiv").toggle();
$("#specificDiv").find("textarea").toggle();
```